# Azure copy blob container contents to another container

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I'm having some issues getting a blob container to copy over to another container. When the copy is complete all that is in the target location is a file with no extension. there should be a bunch of images from the source container. What I'm trying to achieve is creating a backup of a entire Containers blobs. for my case the Container is 0100, but the actual blobs are in 0100/photos/student/ - so if there is a better way please let me know!

[image: target container]

```
      string sBlobConnString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMARTBlobStorageConn"];

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(sBlobConnString);

            //create the blob client
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(srcContainer);
            if (container.Exists())
            {

                CloudBlobDirectory source = container.GetDirectoryReference(blobName);

                var target = container.GetBlockBlobReference(destBlobName);



                var blobs = source.ListBlobs();
                foreach (var blob in blobs)
                {
                    target.StartCopyFromBlob(blob.Uri);
                    copyStates.Add(target.CopyState);
                }

            }
```

For those interested here is the solution on how to copy a Azure blob virtual directory.

```
     public static void CopyDirectory(string srcContainer, string srcDirectory, string destContainer, string destDirectory)
    {
        CloudBlobDirectory sourceBlobDir = GetCloudBlobDirectory(srcContainer, srcDirectory);
        CloudBlobDirectory destBlobDir = GetCloudBlobDirectory(destContainer, destDirectory);

        CopyDirectoryOptions options = new CopyDirectoryOptions()
        {                
            Recursive = true,
        };

        TransferContext context = new TransferContext();           

        // Create CancellationTokenSource used to cancel the transfer
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            TransferManager.CopyDirectoryAsync(sourceBlobDir, destBlobDir, false /* isServiceCopy */, options, context, cancellationSource.Token);            
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the code you have here work? Are you just looking for some advice on making it quicker or a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do you need to do it in  code? Try AzCopy https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#blob-copy

Comment: The code does not work - I need to do this with C# - I'm looking for any advice on fixing this code or perhaps another way to copy a Containers virtual folders to another virtual folder

Comment: You loop through all blobs in the container but you target blob stays the same in that loop. So all is copied to the blob with the name in destBlobName

Comment: after a bit more investigating - this appears to be a limitation of the version of WindowsAzure.Storage I'm using version 2.0. a new library is now available to do what I need https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement